# Change Color On Selection - TableView/SplitView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a `UITableView` for my MasterView of SplitView app.

On selecting any row, the color of that row becomes blue. I want to change it to black or dark grey color. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *tableCell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (tableCell == nil) {
    tableCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease] ;   

[tableCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray]; 
   }
 }
```

Or you can also try this on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if (indexPath.row == selectedIndex) 
{ 
    Cell.LblDynamicCell.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    Cell.LblBackView.backgroundColor=[UIColor Black];
}
//LblDynamicCell,LblBackView objects  declare in cellViewController class

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
  [self.ResultTbl reloadData];

 }
```

Comment: what is tableCell ?? Where should I declare it ?

Comment: kz .. are there also any other color schemes apart from blue and grey ?? like Red or Black ?? I tried using the code line of : "cell.selectionStyle = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:1.0];" but it not seem to work  :-/

Comment: @gamersoul Seems to me like you are trying to do something out of your reach. Relax, put your project on hold for a couple of weeks, learn more basic stuff about programming and try again.

Comment: In order to use a style other than blue or grey, you will have to implement UITableViewCell's "selectedBackgroundView" property, and draw the desired appearance from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Following enum is defined for selection style -

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone,
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue,
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray
} UITableViewCellSelectionStyle;
```

So for your purpose you can use - `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of selected cell as follows:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated

    {
        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

        UIImageView *theImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageName:@"table_selected_cell.png"]];
        self.selectedBackgroundView = theImageView;
        [theImageView release];
    }
```

to change the color of your choice, where table_selected_cell.png is a 2px image of your color.